# Is Unkown equivalent to Null in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, logical-operators

I have a few complex comparisons in my queries and I wanted to make sure I understand the logic correctly in the presence of nulls. It seems "unknown" is the same thing as "null" in PostgreSQL, and I wasn't expecting that.

This is my example:

```
create table tab (col int);

insert into tab (col) values (7), (11), (null);


select col,
  (col = 7) is true as is_true,
  (col = 7) is false as is_false,
  (col = 7) is unknown as is_unknown,
  (col = 7) is null as is_null
  from tab;
```

it shows the output:

```
+-----+--------+---------+-----------+--------+
|a    |is_true |is_false |is_unknown |is_null |
+-----+--------+---------+-----------+--------+
|7    |true    |false    |false      |false   |
|11   |false   |true     |false      |false   |
|null |false   |false    |true       |**true**|
+-----+--------+---------+-----------+--------+
```

Isn't the very last value supposed to be "false" instead of "true"?

Comment: Since `NULL` is an _unknown_ value, it could theoretically be 7, the result of any comparison is _unknown_ aka `Null`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter "...is unknown aka Null": so you confirm that unknown is equivalent to null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what the SQL standard has to say about the NULL value:

> Every data type includes a special value, called the *null value*, sometimes denoted by the keyword `NULL`. This value differs from other values in the following respects:
>
> - Since the null value is in every data type, the data type of the null value implied by the keyword `NULL` cannot be inferred; hence `NULL` can be used to denote the null value only in certain contexts, rather than
>   everywhere that a literal is permitted.
> - Although the null value is neither equal to any other value nor not equal to any other value — it is *unknown* whether or not it is equal to any given value — in some contexts, multiple null values are treated together; for example, the <group by clause> treats all null values together.

This is what the standard has to say about boolean values:

> The data type boolean comprises the distinct truth values *True* and *False*. Unless prohibited by a NOT NULL constraint, the boolean data type also supports the truth value *Unknown* as the null value. This specification does not make a distinction between the null value of the boolean data type and the truth value *Unknown* that is the result of an SQL <predicate>, <search condition>, or <boolean value expression>; they may be used interchangeably to mean exactly the same thing.

So for a `boolean`, `IS NULL` is the same as `IS UNKNOWN`. You could say that it is somewhat silly to declare an “unknown” value if you then say that it is the same as NULL, but such are the ways of the SQL standard.

However, it gives rise to the following statement which feels like a deep truth when you consider how many people understand NULL properly:

```
SELECT NULL IS UNKNOWN;

 ?column? 
══════════
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. That means "unkown" is rendered as null according to the standard. Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

The question:

When `a IS NULL`, what is the result of the following expression:

> (a = 7) is null

> Isn't the very last value supposed to be "false" instead of "true"?

From the SQL specification:

> The data type boolean comprises the distinct truth values True and False. Unless prohibited by a NOT NULL
> constraint, the boolean data type also supports the truth value Unknown as the null value.

The following derives from the above, explicitly:

The answer:

No.  `a = 7`, when `a IS NULL`, is `NULL`.  Then `NULL IS NULL` is `true`.